# Kotlin Synthetic properties

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have noticed that Kotlin synthetic properties don't work on CustomViews. I don't know if it is intended or not. When reading the generated java class, i see the cache is present:

```
private HashMap _$_findViewCache;
```

but is never used. Instead, any time a view is needed, `findViewById` is called. Is this the default behavior? Synthetic properties only working on activities and fragments?

Comment: `_$_findViewCache` fields are automatically generated in `Activity` and `Fragment` classes. Do you have `_$_findViewCache` inside your custom View class?

Comment: yes. the code is generated (the map and the cache function are there). But accessing a property via syntehetic is translated into findViewById byte code (i see it through the 'Kotlin Bytecode' option)

Comment: this is kinda critical if its a bug. specially in views that perform animations, in which findViewbyId is called so many times. Let me know if you need any extra info

Comment: @yanex is this supposed to be the default behavior or am i missing sth?

Comment: I will investigate this shortly.

Comment: I mean, caching in Views is not supported now, and the `findViewById` call generation is an intended behavior, but the caching function presence is definitely a bug.

Comment: oh i didnt know. that, every syntetic property on views triggers a call to findViById which isnt optimal on views with animations

Comment: @yanes another question, iv noticed that every call to a view in activity triggers a getter that has a cast inside it. so everytime we use it, it has that cast. is this supposed to be like this?

Answer (score 2):

[This works now. Blog post on kotlin-android-extensions](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/)

The custom class shall have the cache generated and use it:

```
itemTitle.text = "Hello World!"
```

this in a custom view class, becomes:

```
((TextView)this._$_findCachedViewById(id.itemTitle)).setText((CharSequence)"Hello World!");
```

utilizing the cache properly